# How to deal with previously valid Flyway migrations that became invalid

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Flyway for database migrations in Postgres.

It's about four years old now, so we're talking Flyway 4.0.3, Spring Boot 1.3.x, and Postgres 9.x. Versions could probably be upgraded, but I'd like to fix any existing issues before doing that.

In the meantime, Postgres was upgraded to higher than 9.x. Unfortunately, with that, a few of the existing migrations became outdated as they contain deprecated syntax. So now starting the app with a fresh database (i.e. in a development environment) leads to those migrations failing. In production it is fine as those migrations already have already been applied and won't be again.

I am curious as to what the best practices are to go about this. I can't just go and fix the syntax in the existing migrations, as this will lead to the checksums in the production environment failing. I know `repair` is a thing, however I am unsure how it works and how to use it with Spring Boot.

Failing SQL:

```
UPDATE config
SET (description) = 'my description'
WHERE ...
```

Correct SQL:

```
UPDATE config
SET description = 'my description'
WHERE ...
```

Error:

```
Message    : ERROR: source for a multiple-column UPDATE item must be a sub-SELECT or ROW() expression
```

**EDIT 24/04/2020 Spring Boot solution:**

After Grant Fitchey posted the correct answer about how to use `repair` for this below, I am just going to add how I did this with Spring Boot specifically. I just created a bean of `FlywayMigrationStrategy` that calls 
`repair` before it calls `migrate`:

```java
@Bean
public FlywayMigrationStrategy cleanMigrateStrategy() {
    return flyway -> {
        flyway.repair();
        flyway.migrate();
    };
}
```

When deploying this to the production environment, during startup the checksums in the `schema_versions` table in Postgres were fixed. In another version I will remove the `flyway.repair();` line again, as otherwise obviously this would create the risk of applying invalid migrations.

Comment: could you give some example of migration that failed ? deprecated syntax should not be result in errors.....

Comment: I've edited my question @CodeScale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the repair option. I don't know directly how to call it through spring boot, but the [documentation is here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/repair). This should take care of exactly what you're looking for.

So the first step in this case would be to fix the migrations so they execute correctly in the development environment. Development should now be fine, and flyway should migrate successfully.

On production you should now get a validation error because the checksums differ. Flyway repair will 'repair' the schema history table so that the checksums it has stored match the new ones on disk, and therefore flyway validation passes again.
Specifically what flyway repair is doing is making the schema history table match what you have on disk. It updates all the checksums for applied migrations to the checksums of the ones you have on disk (and therefore, only use this if you are confident the changes are identical). It also removes all failed migration entries from the table (again, only use this once you have cleaned up the database yourself).

Comment: Yep, I thought so, this is why I mentioned it in my question. It is unclear to me however how to use it in Spring Boot. Can't say I found great documentation about it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I know Flyway well, but Spring Boot is a mystery.

Comment: Can you maybe - regardless of Spring Boot - describe exactly what repair would dop for me in this specific scenario? I.e. I have a production environment where the migrations have already been applied, and a fresh development environment where that's not the case. How can I change my migrations to the correct syntax and use repair to make it work on all envs?

Comment: It's long winded, so I'm going to add it to the answer. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks for this! I made it work with Spring Boot as well. I will accept your answer and just add the Spring Boot part to my question.